# Java - add object from ArrayList while removing from another + JListx2

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, jlist, arrays

I have two ArrayLists of the type "Member": ArrayList. One is populated with Members records from a database, and the other is empty!

I also have two JLists in my GUI plus one "Add" button and one "Remove" button.

I want to populate the first JList with the value from the field "Name" inside each the objects of type "Member" in the first ArrayList. When i choose one name from the JList and push "Add", the selected object should go to the second JList, and the second ArrayList, and be removed from the first JList and the first ArrayList.

As far as i understand, it is only possible to populate a JList with a string array? Is this correct?

Does it make sense? Can you help me? :)

Comment: as a part of your solution... moving it from first arraylist to the second arraylist will be done like this:

secondArrayList.add(firstArrayList.remove(index));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To modify the contents of a `JList`, you need to create your own `DefaultListModel`. Then, you can construct the `JList` using the constructor `JList(DefaultListModel)`.

`JList`s can use any object. They will call `toString()` to get the string to display for each object.

Say that the user wants to remove the `index`th object from the first list and add it to the second.

To remove the object from the first list model, use `remove()`:

```
Member member=arrayList1.remove(index);
listModel1.remove(index);
```

To add the object to the second list model, use `addElement()`:

```
listModel2.addElement(member);
arrayList2.add(member);
```